# Send list of controls to UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Hi i want to create control which will have configurable columns (something like dataGrid but with additional features). In xaml i want to have something like this:

```
<MyGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}">
    <MyGrid.Columns>
        <MyGridTextColumn Header="Serial Number" Value="{Binding Id}" />
        <MyGridTextColumn Header="Customer" Value="{Binding Customer}" />
        <MyGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Is active" Value="{Binding IsActive}" />
    </MyGrid.Columns>
</MyGrid>
```

I've created in background code property with list of object, i've tried a lot of things but setter is never run.

```
public partial class MyGrid : UserControl
{

    private List<Object> _columns;
    public List<Object> Columns
    {
        get { return _columns; }
        set
        {
            _columns = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this something else i need to do to add these property? I also tried with DependencyProperty but it also does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have in mind that the setter will be called when creating the List of columns not when filling it with columns.

The xaml

```
<MyGrid.Columns>
    <MyGridTextColumn Header="Serial Number" Value="{Binding Id}" />
    <MyGridTextColumn Header="Customer" Value="{Binding Customer}" />
    <MyGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Is active" Value="{Binding IsActive}" />
</MyGrid.Columns>
```

just adds columns to an existing collection, does not create a new one.

Comment: Thanks, it works, i just had to load it at Loaded event.